# Haskell/ghci Exception: bind: resource busy (Address already in use)

Tags: networking, haskell, ghci

I'm trying to work on following code below (code is a copy from [here](http://cogsandlevers.blogspot.no/2013/05/a-tcp-server-haskell-example.html)). Problem is that when I close the server with ctrl+c and try to run it again I get: *** Exception: bind: resource busy (Address already in use).

In documentation of listenOn is written: NOTE: To avoid the "Address already in use" problems popped up several times on the GHC-Users mailing list we set the ReuseAddrsocket option on the listening socket. If you don't want this behavior, please use the lower level listen instead. Please how can I fix this? (ghci version 7.6.3)

```
import Network (listenOn, accept, PortID(..))  
import Network.Socket (Socket, isSupportedSocketOption, SocketOption(..))
import System.IO (hSetBuffering, hGetLine, hPutStrLn, BufferMode(..), Handle)                                                                        
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)                                        

echoImpl :: Handle -> IO ()                                               
echoImpl client = do                                                      
    line <- hGetLine client                                                
    hPutStrLn client line                                                  
    echoImpl client                                                        

clientHandler :: Socket -> IO ()                                          
clientHandler socket = do                                                        
    (client, _, _) <- accept socket                                          
    hSetBuffering client NoBuffering                                       
    forkIO $ echoImpl client                                               
    clientHandler socket                                                     

felix :: IO () 
felix = do
    let reuseAddrSupported = isSupportedSocketOption ReuseAddr
    putStrLn $ "ReuseAddr: " ++ show reuseAddrSupported
    socket <- listenOn $ PortNumber 5002
    putStrLn $ "Echo server started .."
    clientHandler socket
```

Comment: Works for me on debian x86_64, ghc-7.6.3, network-2.4.1.2. What os, ghc and network are you using?

Comment: Also what `isSupportedSocketOption ReuseAddr` returns? It is possible that network's `configure` script failed to detect `SO_REUSEADDR` option support, and it was disabled.

Comment: isSupportedSocketOption ReuseAddr returns True. I have edited the code so that it prints out the ReuseAddr value now. Network is network-2.4.1.2. OS is osx 10.7.5, ghc/ghci 7.6.3. Just to be sure - this behavior happens in ghci

Comment: I think you should create a ticket in the bug tracker, https://github.com/haskell/network/issues

Comment: thanks, have created new issue in bug tracker